# how to find type of GDI

Tags: winapi, gdi, jna

i am beginner in win 32 api . i try use win 32 api for create an onscreen keyboard . I can give handle of window and components by click but how to realize type of these and i want set text only on text box and editable components

i try to use GetWindowInfo() and try use atomWindowType of window for realize type of that but this is not use full for this goal because this change on each restart of OS.

(click is handle of window)

WINDOWINFO pwi = new WINDOWINFO(); USER32INST.GetWindowInfo(click, pwi); if (pwi.atomWindowType != -15891) { setLastclick(click); } tnx

Comment: I don't think I understand, but in case I'm close, [`GetClassName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may help you..

Comment: some GDI such as textbox and textarae and combo , ... have Edit className . GetClassName is use full but only for GDI . i need solution for all place such as web browsers components. offten apps for editable component use other class name.

Comment: I don't know why would it matter the type of edit control, as long as it is something you can type onto.. OTOH, I see the difficulty caused with many applications using non-standard controls, and not to mention many application's controls are not even windows with respect to the api to begin with. AAMOF I agree with David's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to achieve what you desire, in full generality it is not realistically possible.

A window's type (or class) is essentially determined by its `WndProc`. You can use `GetClassName` and its ilk to help you identify some standard window classes, but as you have already discovered, most real-world apps will not use these standard classes.

So, although in theory, you could analyse the code behind the `WndProc` at runtime, in practice this is not remotely feasible.

Comment: i try ask self question with different way . look at to microsoft onscreen keyboard and try use it on web browser components . how do it ?????  class name of google textbox on IE is "Internet Explorer_server" and on mozilla is "MozillaWindowClass" and class name of components that generated by AWT(java Desktop) is "SunAwtFrame"   _**how to set text of Google search box by APIs?**_SetWindowText and SendMessage() are not able for this goal?

Comment: most on screen keyboards just call SendInput and fake input which is sent to whatever has the input focus. At least that's my understanding.

Comment: work by focus and use GetFocus for give handle of click is not stable solution such as rename files . main problems are get handle of browser component and a way to set text in every text box such as browser

Comment: You don't use GetFocus. You just send the input to whatever has the input focus and let it deal with the consequences. I believe that I've answered your original question. If you want to ask how to write on screen keyboard that is a new question but you should accept this answer unless you believe it to be incorrect.

Comment: in fact i need recognize type of GDI an load OSK only for editable GDI?